# Какая разница между pushState и replaceState?

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-history-api

Подскажите пожалуйста какая разница между `pushState` и `replaceState`?

Comment: такая же как и между добавить в коробку предмет и заменить предмет лежащий сверху.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pushState` добавляет пункт в историю.

`replaceState` заменяет текущий пункт в истории.

Искренне ваш, К.О.

Comment: спасибо! `вперёд/назад`  работает оба функций?

Comment: @KYRAN Да. Дано: [a, b]. push(c)+back=>b, replace(c)+back=>a.

Comment: Спасибо помогло